# MySQL Workbench autocomplete is not showing full sql syntax , table and table column names

Tags: mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench autocomplete is not showing full sql syntax , table and table column names
when autocompletes triggers.

I am using MySQL workbench on MAC Os & below is mysql workbench version

[image]

> **Already tried solution**:  but not working deleting the cache folder as per
> [documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html#wb-configuring-files-cache) but not working

screenshot is attached

1. Incomplete table name
   [image: Incomplete table name]
2. Incomplete sql syntax
   [image: Incomplete sql syntax]
3. Incomplete table column name
   [image: Incomplete table column name]